# How do read file by filtering rows based on a condition in R

Tags: r, read.csv

I am using R to read a csv. But I do not want whole dataset in memory as dataset is too large. I need to read rows based on one column's category.

I want to read only rows where col2 = 'A'

**Example :**
**col1   col2   col3**
1      A      1000 
2      B      2000 
3      A      1000 
4      A      2000 
5      A      1000 
6      B      2000

Answer (score 7):

You could try to use `fread` from `data.table` package with `cmd` option. From [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.8/topics/fread):

> A shell command that pre-processes the file; e.g.
> fread(cmd=paste("grep",word,"filename"). See Details.
>
> Shell commands:
>
> fread accepts shell commands for convenience. The input command is run
> and its output written to a file in tmpdir (link{tempdir}() by
> default) to which fread is applied "as normal". The details are
> platform dependent -- system is used on UNIX environments, shell
> otherwise; see system.

So if you run something like

```
library(data.table)
t <- fread(......., cmd=paste("grep","' A '","filename"), .....)
```

then it filters lines which contains `A` (A surrounded by spaces) and then apply `fread` to the result.

Comment: I think if the data is really big, perhaps `vroom` would be useful

Comment: @akrun First time I heard about `vroom` package, looks interesting. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

We could use `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
df1 <- read.csv.sql("file.csv", "select *, from file where col2 = 'A'", sep=",")
```

Comment: Is it (SQL filter) happens to run after reading whole file? OP said he doesn't want whole file in memory.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux it imports data into a temporary SQLite database and then reads it into R.

Comment: Ah, I see. I proposed to use fread with shell and grep, where filter happens to run before reading whole file

Answer (score 0):

One of these should solve the issue:

```
fread(file=file_name, select=col_names)[specific_col_name %in% ID_name]
```

or

```
fread(file=file_name, select=col_names)[grep(pattern, specific_col_name, ignore.case = TRUE)]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This loads all data first and then filters. It answers the question but is less optimal than `cmd` option.